# Annoying pop-up hint after updating to Gradle 5.0

Tags: gradle, kotlin

Just updated to Gradle 5.0 and now I get this [pop-up hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeSbS.jpg):

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" // 'classpath' in 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.GString)'
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.4'
        classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'maven'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.3.10"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "2.0.4"
}

ext.moduleName = 'com.github.kotlin_graphics.kotlin_unsigned'

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"  // 'implementation' in 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.GString)'

    testImplementation 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.1.10'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap" }
    maven { url = "https://jitpack.io" }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}

jar {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    manifest {  // here
        attributes('Automatic-Module-Name': moduleName)
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Why? And how may I solve?

Comment: I tried your build file in an empty directory with both Gradle 4.10.x and 5.0 and both work fine.  Are you running Gradle with a specific JDK? are you running the version of Gradle you think you are?  Are you running Gradle with specific tasks?

Comment: Do you have a settings.gradle file?  a gradle.properties file?  Can you show those as well please?

Comment: 1.8. I guess I'm running 5.0 because I can see new outputs I never saw before: "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0." Sure, I just [pushed](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/kotlin-unsigned/tree/gradle5.0), `gradle5.0` branch. Ps: using Idea 2018.3

Comment: You have something else environmental on your machine because that branch runs fine and fails on a unit test.

Comment: I just noticed that myself. Funny thing is that `master` with `4.10.2` works flawless

Comment: Check env variables you are setting, anything with Gradle, Groovy, JAVA_HOME, that could cause something else to come into play here.  Your top level gradle.property file as well.  It is something outside of this code.

Comment: Clear your Gradle cache dir.  Run using `./gradlew` in case you have maybe an RC Gradle 5 in your path.

Comment: Is this an ERROR or a WARNING you are getting, your comments below now make it sound like a WARNING but your question above makes this sound like more of a serious ERROR (although it says "error/warning" which is unclear).  Also SHOW the actual message with the word "error" or "warning" as displayed in the output, don't just indicate it exists.

Comment: Ok, so you have no WARNING really, you have an IDE static analysis pop-up hint in the editor showing you a fake message that does not affect running of Gradle in any way, it is a bad message from the IDE.  You should not change your build file.  It runs correctly yes, and Gradle shows no warning yes?  then this is a non issue.

Comment: Ok, modified once again to use the right syntax

Comment: If you want IDE help that is perfect, move away from Groovy based `build.gradle` to the Kotlin based build script, it is fully type safe and fully correct when used in the IDE.  A Groovy file sometimes is misinterpreted.

Comment: I updated my answer below to be clearer about what is going on.

Comment: Believe me, I'd really love to do that, but I tried quickly yesterday evening and it was a nightmare.. I guess I'll create again another branch and try there

Comment: You don't need to do it, but until you do, ignore Groovy static analysis hints on a Gradle build file that might be incorrect.  You will see many.  If you do not see the error or warning when running under Gradle you are likely OK.

Comment: IN the future, please include the full information without an interpretation of the information.  Sometimes this causes people to go down the wrong path.  instead of "I have a Gradle warning/error that says ..." it was "When editing my build.gradle file I see this popup hint that worries me, but does not affect running my build.  Is it a problem?"

Comment: Yeah sure, I always try to describe at best the problem, however sometime what I think is clear isnt for others. But there is absolute no problem on my side, I'm totally open to suggestion and critics to improve my answer :)

Comment: All good, we got it figured out!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace it with:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.10"
```

then there is no [GString](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/lang/GString.html) being used.

Comment: This seems to be the reason. Also, this is better: `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version".toString()`

Comment: This is not a good suggestion to use non-idiomatic code to remove the warning. .

Comment: If you notice, when run on a clean system, these errors or warnings do not appear.

Comment: @JaysonMinard while it avoids the issue, this is perfectly fine. there's no need to get religious about it.

Comment: I edited directly the answer, tell me guys if this is fine and makes everybody happy now :)

Comment: The updated question now shows clearly that your suggestion here is invalid.  There is no actual error in Gradle.  The message is an IDE static analysis tip that doesn't know enough about the build file to give correct information.  So this suggested change is silly, and isn't needed.  Gradle reports absolutely no problem, only the editor reports a false static analysis tip.

Comment: So given only your answer, the person asking the question would think he has a Gradle problem and then litter his future `build.gradle` files with silly `toString()` calls for no reason.  There is no change required in the `build.gradle` file, if you now read the fully debugged version of what was happening.

Comment: have replaced it with the my version again, because it did not avoid the use of `GString` anymore, which I'd consider vandalism because the code did not match the meta information provided. and not to use static version numbers is purely a personal preference - and hardly anything authoritative. all across Google's SDK documentation one can find that... and Gradle documentation also does not suggest or outlaw anything - therefore I'd consider it a lame argument. if you wish "a better answer", edit your's.

Answer (score 0):

**You have no actual real issue to worry about.**  Based on your updated question and screenshots, you have an IDE static analysis hint popping up that is incorrect.  You do not have any error or warning message from Gradle.  You have something in your text editor that is misleading.

This happens at times when the code you are showing, for example, your `build.gradle` which is Groovy code, cannot be fully interpreted to know what the correct types are.  In this case, nothing is wrong.  This is a red herring and should be ignored.

You can safely ignore this IDE message, you will receive other misleading ones at times on `build.gradle` files.  If you want correct IDE help with writing a build file, switch to the fully type safe Kotlin version of gradle build files.  The Groovy version is never perfect in the IDE for messages you receive.

Testing your `build.gradle` on empty dir:

```
$ ./gradlew build

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
7 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 5 up-to-date
```

And testing it directly from your GitHub repo: (*note: you have some dangerous classpath issues there in a warning that should be resolved*)

```
$ ./gradlew clean build
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    /Users/xyz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.50/9fab8887f91c8e17cce1a7522f45dc25976e57b9/kotlin-reflect-1.2.50.jar (version 1.2)
    /Users/xyz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.31/95d6a67e8787280a82a2059e54e4db7ac6cfe74/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.31.jar (version 1.2)
    /Users/xyz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.10/b178c1501609c6e4ee8be635513cb023a466457d/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar (version 1.3)
    /Users/xyz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.10/1b19d99229dcedad7caf50534dce38fe82845269/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar (version 1.3)
w: Consider providing an explicit dependency on kotlin-reflect 1.3 to prevent strange errors
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath

> Task :test FAILED

unsigned.Ubyte test > ubyte FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at ubyte.kt:35

unsigned.Uint test > uint FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at uint.kt:32

unsigned.Ulong test > ulong FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at ulong.kt:29

unsigned.Ushort test > ushort FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at ushort.kt:30

6 tests completed, 4 failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/xyz/.../kotlin-unsigned/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5s
10 actionable tasks: 10 executed
```

Notice that Gradle is **not** reporting any messages or errors.  Only your IDE was.

Comment: The classpath issues come from the [kotlintest dependency](https://gist.github.com/elect86/b386011f5a97e73ab3d54dc29dea8c80)

Comment: Also, just to be clear, [this](https://imgur.com/kshzC4P) is what I mean by warnings. Note that I also experience those failed test with `5.0`.

Comment: You should update your question to say "error" or "warning" because "error/warning" is far from clear.  Also, show the actual error or warning instead of just indicating there is one.   You have a problem here you should resolve, both for the dependencies including two versions of Kotlin library, and also your system producing an unusual message that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question removing `error` and also setting the screenshot on `warning` to show clearly what is my problem.
Regarding the dependency issue I just replied two comments early, it's outside my reaching area (or at least it seems so).

Comment: @elect you can force the version on the Kotlin libraries to the current version, it is within your area.  Just add the dependencies to yours with the correct version number and that will force them to yours.  It shouldn't affect that test library.

Comment: It seems indeed that an explicit `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"` solved the classpath warnings. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change warning mode to all or none to avoid the hint.

Add `org.gradle.warning.mode=all` or `org.gradle.warning.mode=none` to your `gradle.properties`